# 'Any pair of them'

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I have 9 elements, chemical reaction can occur between any two of them. How should I express this in a formal way? It is scientific writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are nine elements, any one of which can react with one of the others.

There may be a more "formal" way to say this, but this should get the meaning across.